# SIGNALR for IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, signalr, signalr.client

I want to use signalr for iOS, but I don't have any idea how to use it. Please guide me. I tried to use https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC but it's very confusing.
The zip file that I downloaded from github has lots of things. I don't know which one I need to include in my code.
In the zip file there is a samples work folder also  different folders Mac and iOS along with a folder calledsignalr.client.ios which contains one file named SignalR.Client.iOS-Prefix.

Comment: There are probably some clients out there, but if you read on the official signalr site there are no such "official" clients. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

Answer (score 0):

To add the SignalR-ObjC i made a podFile

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'SignalR-ObjC'
```

then run the pod install command.

maybe this link will help you with the pod process

[Link](http://www.ingens-networks.com/blog/post/2013/04/07/CocoaPods-Administrar-dependencias-de-bibliotecas-en-proyectos-Objective-C.aspx)

and this link maybe help you on how to make the connection and the hub

```
ViewController.h

#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<SignalR.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end




ViewController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SRHubConnection *connection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURL:@"http://www.domain.com/site/"];

    SRHubProxy *myHub = [connection createHubProxy:@"notification"];

    [connection start];
    connection.started = ^{
        [myHub invoke:@"Logon" withArgs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"936DA01F-9ABD-4d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8", nil]];
        [myHub on:@"message" perform:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived: msg: time:)];
    };

}

- (void)notificationReceived:(id)user msg:(id)msginput time:(id)timeinput
{
NSLog(@"%@",user);
NSLog(@"%@",msginput);
NSLog(@"%@",timeinput);
}
```

[Link to a source page](http://www.ingens-networks.com/blog/post/2013/04/09/DyKnowSignalR-ObjC-SignalR-IOS-Client.aspx)

im still having problems invoking the hub methods on the server, i already have a ASP.net page with its javascript client working. but im having issues with the iOS client, so if this help you i hope you can add your progress.

Comment: Please provide a full answer here instead of the links. Or if the content of the links provided is too big, please at least post a snippet of what they might contain.